# Change printer setting between printing job - Zebra printer

Tags: vb.net, zebra-printers, zpl-ii, epl

I can change the printer setting from the printer setting as well as from the Zebra Setup Utilities. What I would like to know is if their is a way to automatically change the settings (darkness or print mode) in between two printing job. Like one job as darkness set to 15 and the other to 3.

I am sending the print job from Visual Basic as a ThermalLabel object.

I already tried using :

```
PrintUtils.SetDarkness(03)
```

as well as :

```
PrintUtils.ExecuteCommand(ligneZPL)
```

where ligneZPL is this string -> "~SD3 \n"

But the printer (Zebra - GC420T) doesn't take it into account.

Comment: According to zebra Docs, G series dont take this into account check this out: https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/knowledge-articles/setting-the-darkness-level-with-the-zpl-language.html. You nbeed to set up manually. Here is how: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G8rGtCKFFgo

Answer (score 2):

There are two values in play for darkness. `~SD` sets the darkness generally.  `^MD` modifies the `~SD` value by a delta.  If  the `~SD` value is 10, and the `^MD` value is 5, then the overall darkness will be 15.

If you want to print most labels at 15, set `~SD15`.  For the label you want to print at 3, set `^MD-12` as part of the code at the top of the label.

Either of these commands might already be embedded in the label you are trying to print.  That may be the reason why the setting seems to be ignored.